# Lambda function "Endpoint request timed out"

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda

I have a lambda function written in javascript (node) that takes a large payload, breaks it down, hits multiple APIs, builds the response, and returns.

The gist of the code looks like so:

```
'use strict';

let API_KEY = '';

exports.createObjects = (event, context, callback) => {
    let promises = createObject(event);
    Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
        let res = [];
        results.forEach((r) => {
            res.push(r.obj);
        });
        callback(null, {"message" : res});
    })
    .catch((e) =>{
        console.log('Error Creating obj ', e);
    });
};

const createObject = (req) => {
    let objects = req.body.obj;
    let promiseReturn = [];
    if(req.headers.Authorization === undefined)
        return promiseReturn;

    API_KEY = req.headers.Authorization;

    objects.forEach((s) => {
        let newPromise = create(s);
        promiseReturn.push(newPromise);
    });
    return promiseReturn;
};


const create = (object) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let chain = createObject(s);
        chain
            .then((res)=>{
                return updateObject(s);
            })
            .then((res)=>{
                return createAttribute1(object.x, object.y);
            })
            .then((res)=>{
                return createAttribute2(object.z, object.q);
            })
            .then((res)=>{
                return createAttribute3(object.s, object.t);
            })          
            .then((res)=>{
                return createAttribute4(object.v, object.c); 
            })  
            .then((finalResponse)=>{
                resolve(finalResponse);
            })  
            .catch((e)=>{
                return rollBack(object);
            })
    });
};
```

I'm having problems dealing with concurrent request.  For example if I hit the lambda function with a 10 mb payload it processes just fine, but If 3 users hit the lambda function with 10mb payloads at the same time i see the error `"Endpoint request timed out"`.

What is the best way to "parallelize" this and move it out of the web server with lambda?  I'm not sure how to approach this...  I have increased the response time from 3 seconds to the maximum of 30 but this only buys a little time and doesn't fix the problem.